# control the emission of object with mouse input in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to enable the emission of the object when we mouse click or touch click on the object. By default, it should be disabled in Unity. Can anyone provide me c# code for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You can access the emission property by doing `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor(yourProperty, yourColor);` You can use SetColor, SetFloat... etc

Comment: This question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null){
            Material mymat = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            mymat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```